# How to auto include https or http in prefix of any url in whole website

Tags: php

i post in URL but display that URL with my site name so,
how to auto add https:// in ?

`<a href="www.google.com">Google</a>`

but display as www.test.com/www.google.com 
and it redirect on www.test.com/www.google.com

i want display only www.google.com and redirect only on www.google.com

i have code as like as

Google
it's should be redirect on www.google.com

now my site is www.test.com

when i post URL then it's display as www.test.com/www.google.com
and when i post https://www.google.com then it display proper
so i can add auto https  or http in any posted URL

Please suggest any idea....

Comment: `<a href="https://www.google.com">Google</a>`?

Comment: The thing is, you should know whether the website supports HTTPS. If it does, you will add it as you add the URL. If it doesn't, you won't do it. There's no way to detect whether it should contain http:// or https:// (as far as I know).

If you are adding your own website's URL, you can use the JavaScript `window.location.protocol` to detect whether your website's URL should be http:// or https:///

Comment: `www.google.com` is a relative URL, and refers to a file or folder of that name below the current one only. You _need_ to specify the protocol when referring to external resources – _at least_ you have to use `//www.google.com`, which would be a protocol-relative URL, meaning the protocol the current page is viewed over will be used to complete this URL to an absolute one. As @Billy already pointed out, that will only work though if the target site supports that protocol. If it doesn’t, or you are not sure, then you should specify the protocol explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want the link to be shown with no protocol, but when you click it it should go to https. Without questioning why would you do that and all the negative impact it might have, it can be easily done using JS:

```
yourAnchor.addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.href = 'https://' + this.href;
})
```

where `yourAnchor` is the DOM anchor element you're modifying (you'll probably select all anchors). You also might want to check if `http` is present in the link and replace it with `https`.

The code above will modify the `href` attribute after you click it and before the redirection happens.

Comment: thanks but this is not work proper.